# How to turn off the pop up selecting menu when holding a key in MacBook

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook

When I trying to hold down a key, the pop up menu will show up as below. I want to turn it off and let my keyboard output like `ccccccc`.
How do I do it?

[image]

Comment: Relevant/dupe on sister site: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/20618/24324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching and trying, I found that the only way to turn off the pop up menu is to run the following command in terminal:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

And remember to restart MacBook to active this change.